# phalcon currently dispatching route name

Tags: phalcon

I use custom routes which include *namespace* besides *controller* and *action*. So for ACL purposes I use MVC route name as ACL resource name. Now I need to obtain currently **DISPATCHING** route name. The only solution I've come up with is to get *namespace/controller/action* from Dispatcher and iterating over all the routes find an appropriate one.

Is there any easiest way to obtain currently **dispatching** (not just matched) route name?

Answer (score 5):

Pretty easy

```
\Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('router')->getMatchedRoute()->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your router, dispatcher and base controller to get what you need. Consider this:

```
$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false);

$routes  = array(
    '/{namespace:"[a-zA-Z]+}/:controller' => array(
        'controller' => 2,
    ),
    '/{namespace:"[a-zA-Z]+}/:controller/:action/:params'       => array(
        'controller' => 2,
        'action'     => 3,
        'params'     => 4,
    ),
);

foreach($routes as $route => $params) {
    $router->add($route, $params);
}
```

Now in your base controller you can do this:

```
public function getNamespace()
{
    return $this->dispatcher->getParam('namespace');
}
```

This way you can have the namespace currently being served in your controllers (so long as they extend your base controller).

If you need to get the namespace in a model you can always use the DI like so (base model):

```
public function getNamespace()
{
    $di = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault();

    return $di->dispatcher->getParam('namespace');
}
```

Comment: Hm, I didn't ask how to obtain dispatching namespace, but **route name**